# Partition the hard drive after Ubuntu 14.04 installation

Tags: partitioning, disk-management

I want to know if I can create a partition on my hard disk after installing Ubuntu on it. I want to create partition as we do it in Windows like D: or E: drives etc.

Now I have done the installation of Ubuntu 13.04 and upgraded it to 14.04.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, to create additional partitions? Sure (under conditions). You mean you want to to name it D:, E:?

Comment: Possible dupe of [How to make a partition windows can read?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145812/how-to-make-a-partition-windows-can-read)

Comment: @bain I didn't read anything about Windows should be able to read it.

Comment: @JacobVlijm In that case it might be a dupe of [How to resize partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions) or more precisely the question [How do I repartition with GParted? duplicate](http://askubuntu.com/questions/51272/how-do-i-repartition-with-gparted)

Comment: @bain No doubt the subject is discussed before. But we need to get clear what exactly is the question before we can point in a direction, or add some specific information. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can but you have to be very carefull as there is a big potential for loosing data if you dont do it right or there is a problem (loss of power)

Before touching partitions make sure any important data has been backed up! Also it would be a good idea to do this when you are not restricted with time. If you have something important to do soon, leave it till you have time that should you have problems you have time to work it out.

Another note, you cannot modify partitions that are mounted, so you cannot be loaded into ubuntu.

You will need to use the live DVD. Look for a program called gparted. It can also be run from the terminal by typing into a terminal

```
sudo gparted
```

If for some reason its not installed (it should be though in a live installer)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Gparted will allow you to make many different modifications to you partitions. Make sure that you select the right partition to modify. Gparted is fairly easy to understand so you should be able to easily work out what partition to modify.

Most general linux users will have only 2 partitions. there root partition \ and a swap partion. (more advanced linux users may have more to seperate the system from there home directory )

When gparted has finished scanning drives, you can select your drive from the upper right side where it says /dev/sdx (xx.xxGB)

For example my laptop HD is /dev/sda

You will see a bar that is split up and that represents your partitions, also you will see them listed.

look at mount point "/" is your root partition.

Resizing is simple, right click on the partition you want to resise and select resize move.

you will get a dialogue with options on resizing.

once you have verified everthing is correct, you can click the apply all changes button.

Depending on hardware and size of your drive it could take some time to complete.