# How to create a partition after installating ubuntu 14.0 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning

i installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS . And i didn't make any partition during installation. so
i want to create/make 3 partition for **/** root,**boot** & **Swap**.
How can i achieve it.

Comment: Did you dual boot or is Ubuntu the only OS on your PC?

Comment: @'Tony Lancer' Only ubuntu is  in my system right now !

Comment: You don't need to create partitions if Ubuntu is the only OS on your system. If you really want to do partitions for swap, boot and root, you'll have to reinstall Ubuntu(provided you have backed up your data), and do it from [there](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation).

Comment: is it work which i already see on this forum  ? the link is [Partition the hard drive after Ubuntu 14.04 installation ](http://askubuntu.com/questions/465757/partition-the-hard-drive-after-ubuntu-14-04-installation)

Comment: @TonyLancer thanks for the valuable reply for me ,But i also want to know ,Is there not a single  way to create  partition for  root ,boot and swap after installing ubuntu 14.0 ,either by the GUI or using Command line ?

Comment: I am sure you can, but it sounds more dangerous, because there is a higher chance of data loss. The "best" way to do it is when you are installing Ubuntu. If you may, someone will help you with your query.

Comment: @**TonyLancer** Thanks Tony for this link. Here i have some doughts from your provided link [that is](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) .  In this there is mention select `primary`  partition for **swap**. So do i select `Logical` for remaining all **/** mean **root**,**boot**,**home** & so on ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45949/discussion-between-clix159-and-tony-lancer).