# Help me for my Ubuntu Partition?

Tags: partitioning

I am new at Ubuntu but very interested. I need help for my drive partitioning.

PC details: DELL Vostro 1014 | HDD 320GB, RAM 2GB and storage media as seen in the following screenshots.
[image]
[image]
[image]

I want to have partition like below:

1. A drive where I can install Ubuntu like C drive of Windows
2. Home like Windows
3. SmallBusiness

I do not need the unallocated or free space
Please help me. Linked images are from my PC. I have tried to make partition. But not good. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend looking into using UnetBootin and GParted to partition the harddrives. http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/ and http://gparted.sourceforge.net/. You will need unetbootin because you cannot partition a HD while mounted. So these websites will give you step by step instructions on downloading and using their software.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ready for reinstallation of the whole system you have an option of merging both ext4 File systems so that you atleast have 33 GB free Space on which you can smoothly run Ubuntu.

For installation help please read this -https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

Comment: I need details instruction one by one. I want to have partition like below:

    1. A drive where I can install Ubuntu like C drive of Windows
    2. Home like Windows
    3. SmallBusiness  Would you please help me?

Comment: how do you want to install from a live media or directly as I can see you are running ubuntu form some live media!! what do you mean by home like windows and SmallBusiness( you have the name of the Drive with 289 GB space right??)   and on more thing this <http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation> can help you

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea! I want to reinstall Ubuntu and need those two partition

Comment: what windows and SmallBusiness  partitions right... and I will add procedure of installation in my answer

Comment: Yes UBUNTU and SmallBusiness. It would be great help for me

Comment: I am waiting for the valuable procedure

Comment: 1. Create live USB 2.Install Ubuntu with(alongSide) Windows (This option is available after you will start installation) 3. Decide how much space you want for each operating system..done it will install the system....

Comment: Have you visited this link? http://w3lab1.wordpress.com/2014/06/12/ubuntu-drive-partition/

Comment: yes that's why i am telling this to you

Comment: I have used there only one OS and that is Ubuntu, no Windows. I need two partition 1. for Ubuntu OS and 2. SmallBusiness.......

Comment: This should be mentioned in question.. read this <http://askubuntu.com/questions/145812/how-to-make-a-partition-windows-can-read>